# Firebase iOS multiple errors when uploading symbol files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm trying to setup Firebase Crash Reporting on a Swift project. I'm using Xcode 7.3. Firebase Crash Reporting version is 1.0.7.

After following all steps properly, this is the error I'm getting on Xcode, which isn't allowing my project to run:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5cpD.jpg

I've also tried to manually upload it using batch-upload, but it gives me an error:

```
./batch-upload: line 121: FIREBASE_API_KEY: environment variable empty or unset

Explicitly add to environment or set GoogleService-Info.plist (-p)
and Info.plist (-i) flags to extract values from the files.

Try "./batch-upload -h" for details.
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

To get the Xcode script to work, the invocation in your run script phase needs to look something like

```
    # Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:1234567890123:ios:1234abc567de89

# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Users/yourname/yourproject/Your Project Name-5632e387efda6.json"
```

The JSON file is a file you've downloaded after creating a service account in the Firebase Console. Here's [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files) on how to do that.

To get batch-upload to work, the invocation of that script is more complicated and might look something like

```
batch-upload -p path/to/your/project/GoogleService-Info.plist -i path/to/your/project/Info.plist  path/to/your/service/account/file/Your\ Project\ Name-abc123def456.json path/to/something.dSYM/DWARF/SomeBinaryName
```

I'm apologize for this process being a bit arduous and arcane--it's definitely something we're aware of and working on fixing!

Comment: additionally, our support for Swift versions > 1 isn't great. This will be fixed in our next update.

Comment: where you get these ID 1:1234567890123:ios:1234abc567de89 , it look like we need to configure 2 ID in GOOGLE_APP_ID

Comment: from the comment right above it:
    # Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file

Answer (score 0):

Answer from: firebase-support@google.com

Can you go over the following items and see it will work:

reset your OAuth credentials, run below command:

```
rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*
```

create new service account and make sure it has editor permission
Revise your script into below format:

```
 # Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
   GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

   # Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
   "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"
```

Remember to follow the instructions on [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files)

Please make sure your app id and json file path are correct.
I hope this helps.